# Make global accessable configuration for MySQLi in PHP

Tags: php, config

I want to make a 'config.php', in which user and password of the MySQLi connection are saved. But I want to access to it at a 'global scale' (in functions as well). Is there a better method than using 'global $var' or '$_GLOBALS['config']' or how is it convenient to declare settings like this?

Comment: use define() for the same. define('VARIABLE_NAME', 'variable value');

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Thanks. Is it possible to make the variable value to a mysqli connection like 'define("Con",new mysqli(...));' or is there an alternative way for this so I don't have to write everytime '$Var = new mysqli(Host,User,Pass,DB);'?

Comment: Yeah.. You can do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In your config.php, define some global constants:

```
define('MYSQL_HOST','hostname');
define('MYSQL_USER','username');
define('MYSQL_PASS','password');
define('MYSQL_DB','dbname');
```

Create another file called db.php or similar, which contains a function that returns an instance of the database connection:

```
require_once 'config.php';    
function getConnection(){
      $link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS,MYSQL_DB) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
      return $link;
}
```

Then in any scripts you have that require a database connection, include the following:

```
include 'db.php';
$con = getConnection();
```